# Making dictionary from string cuts all values except first two

Tags: python, json, dictionary

There is a string:

```
mystring = "{"1" : "a", "2" : "b", "3" : "c", "4" : "d"}"
```

I try to make dictionary from it with:

```
mydict = json.loads(mystring)
```

It's making a dictionary but it makes it only from two first pair of key and value, so it looks like:

```
{'1':'a', '2':'b'}
```

I tried also:

```
mydict = dict((k.strip(), v.strip()) for k, v in
                 (item.split(':') for item in mystring.split(',')))
```

But there is the same problem. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: your `mystring` given isn't even valid. Please recheck it to make sure it works in the first place.

Comment: If you mean that there was no quotes, thats my fault in writing question, I added it.

Comment: No, try running your first line of code as it currently stands.

Comment: use `mystirng = '{"1" : "a", "2" : "b", "3" : "c", "4" : "d"}'` and it will work as expected. If you start a string with `"` the next `"` will end the string, this is why your `mystring` is not valid. **Voting to close this as it is  a simple type-o**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quotes around your string:

```
>>> import json
>>> mystring = '{"1" : "a", "2" : "b", "3" : "c", "4" : "d"}'
>>> mydict = json.loads(mystring)
>>> mydict
{'1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'c', '4': 'd'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be that you are using double quote before the curly brackets and after one. You must know that this a mistake.

Comment: You guys all right, I didn't noticed that, maybe too tired, sorry for your loss of time